# Nondeterministic linear time vs. the deterministic time hierarchy

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, time-complexity, nondeterminism

How much is known about nondeterministic linear time?  I'm aware that $$ \mathrm{NTIME}(n) \neq \mathrm{DTIME}(n).$$
Is there an $m > 1$ so that $\mathrm{NTIME}(n) \not\subset \mathrm{DTIME}(n^m)$?  Are there any arguments that $\mathrm{NTIME}(n) \subset \mathrm{P}$ should be unlikely?

Comment: NTIME(n)⊆P is equivalent to P=NP by padding argument.

Comment: Ahh wonderful, that answers my question very quickly!  I shouldn't really need the other part of the question at this point.  Thank you!

Comment: And no value k>1 is known such that NTIME(n)⊈DTIME(n^k), because even a value k>1 with a weaker condition NTIME(n^k)⊈DTIME(n^k) is not known.  See [this question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1079) by Bruno and the answer by Ryan Williams.  (The linked question only talks about k≥2, but if we knew that NTIME(n^k)⊈DTIME(n^k) for some noninteger k between 1 and 2, then we would also know NTIME(n^2)⊈DTIME(n^2) again by padding argument.)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, could you post your comments as an answer so the question becomes answered?